# What is the simplest way to wire two resistors to be controlled by one switch to have three possible resistances and an off position?

Tags: switches, parallel, series

There is very little space in the equipment's cabinet. Just enough space for two power resistors and one switch. Can a switch like this

[image: Double pole five throw switch]

be wired to for example provide (using two 50Ω resistors) provide 50, 100, and 25Ω as well as an off position?

Here is where I'm trying to start: A DPDT CENTER OFF SWITCH with two of the three positions shown.

[image: DPDT CENTER OFF SWITCH WIRED TO PROVIDE SERIES PARALLEL & OFF]

Comment: You certainly need more than just a DPDT switch; you need at least a DP3T with an off position, possibly even a (very unusual) 3P3T with off position.

Comment: What sort of current are we talking about here? 1 mA, 100 A? And is OFF short-circuit or open-circuit? In either case you're looking for four results so you're going to need a 4-way switch.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

*Figure 1. A 2-pole, 4-way, rotary switch solution for **∞**, 25 Ω, 50 Ω and 100 Ω selection.*

[image]

*Figure 2. A 2-pole, 4-way, rotary switch solution for **0 Ω**, 25 Ω, 50 Ω and 100 Ω selection.*